# Contact Manager with exception handling in Python

Tags: python

I need to add exception handling to this program. If the program can’t find the CSV file, it should display an appropriate message and create a new CSV file that doesn’t contain any contact data. For the view and delete commands, display an appropriate error message if the user enters an invalid integer or an invalid contact number.

```
import csv
import sys

FILENAME = "contacts.csv"


def read_contacts():
    try:
        contacts = []
        with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                contacts.append(row)
        return contacts
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
       print("Could not find " + FILENAME + " file.")
       f=open(FILENAME, "w+")

       return contacts
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e), e)
        exit_program()


def write_contacts(contacts):
    try:
        with open (FILENAME, "w", newline="") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerows(contacts)

    except OSError as e:
        print(type(e), e)
        exit_program()
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e), e)
        exit_program()


def list_contacts(contacts):
    try:
        for i in range(0, len(contacts)):
           contact = contacts[i]
           print(str(i+1) + ". " + contact[0]+ "(" + str(contact[1]) +")" )
           print()

    except:
        try:
            if len(contact) == 0:
               print("There are no contacts in the list.\n")
            else:
                print(type(e), e)
                return

        except:
           print(type(e), e)
           return

def view_contacts(contacts):
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input("Number: "))


        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer. Please try again.")
            continue

    if number < 1 or number > len (contacts):
        print("Invalid contact number")
        print()
    else:


            contact = contacts[number-1]
            print("Name: " + contact[0])
            print("Email: " + contact[1])
            print("Phone: " + contact[2])
            print()


def add_contacts(contacts):
    name = input("Name: ")
    email = input("Email: ")
    phone = input("Phone: ")
    contact = []
    contact.append(name)
    contact.append(email)
    contact.append(phone)
    contacts.append(contact)
    write_contacts(contacts)
    print(name + " was added")
    print()


def delete_contacts(contacts):
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input("Number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer.")
            continue


        if number < 0 or number > len (contacts):
            print("invalid number")


        else:
           break
        contact = contacts.pop(number-1)
        write_contacts(contacts)
        print(contact[0] + " was deleted")


def display_menu():

    print("Contact Manager")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("list - Display all contacts", "\nview - View a contact",
          "\nadd - Add a contact", "\ndel - Delete a contact",
          "\nexit - Exit program")

    print()

##definition main menu
def main():


    display_menu()
    contacts =  read_contacts()
    while True:
        command = input("Command: ")
        if command.lower() == "list":
            list_contacts(contacts)
        elif command.lower() == "view":
            view_contacts(contacts)
        elif command.lower() == "add":
            add_contacts(contacts)
        elif command.lower() == "del":
            delete_contacts(contacts)
        elif command.lower() == "exit":
            print("Good bye!")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid command. Please try again.\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You could just open the file with append mode which will create the file if it doesn't exist.

```
except FileNotFoundError as e:
       print("Could not find " + FILENAME + " file.")
       f=open(FILENAME, "a")

       # the value of contacts would be [] here
       return []
```